# Android SoundPool plays no sound

Tags: android, android-studio, soundpool

I want to play a short sound when a button is clicked using SoundPool. But when the button is clicked no sound appears despite the Log telling me it's loaded and "playing". The soundfile is an .ogg in case that's relevant. Here's my code, `buttonSound()` is called in `onCreate()`.

```
void buttonSound(){
    AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .build();

    soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder().setAudioAttributes(attributes).build();

    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
            int status) {
            Log.d("SOUNDPOOL", "COMPLETE "+button);
        }
    });
    button = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.button, 1);

}


public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_back:
            // Sound loaded
            if(button != 0) {
                soundPool.play(button, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
                Log.d("PLAYING", "PLAYING");
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently `AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION` was the issue, it works fine with `AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME` and `AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA`. I have no idea why, though.